# Some char arrays don't end with '\0'

Tags: c, arrays, char, string-literals, termination

I have a simple code in C to see if three same char arrays all end with `'\0'`:

```
int main(){
    char a[4] = "1234";
    char b[4] = "1234";
    char c[4] = "1234";


    if(a[4] == '\0')
            printf("a end with '\\0'\n");
    if(b[4] == '\0')
            printf("b end with '\\0'\n");
    if(c[4] == '\0')
            printf("c end with '\\0'\n");

    return 0;
}
```

But the output shows that only array b ends with terminator `'\0'`. Why is that? I supposed all char arrays have to end with `'\0'`.

Output:

> b end with '\0'

Comment: You declared the arrays with space for 4 bytes, but you’re trying to read byte 5.

Comment: Buy a good beginners book. When you do all the exercises in it, you can  start to look for the errors in the compiler :D

Comment: "I supposed all `char` arrays have to end with `'\0'`."-- Nope. All _strings_ must end with a `\0` terminator, but character arrays without the null-terminator are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @DavidBowling but is it okay to initialize the 4 sized char array with a 5 sized char array?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya-- well, you can't initialize an array with another array; you initialize with a string literal or with an initializer list. Extra elements in the initializer are ignored, so the result of using `char a[4] = "1234";` is that `a` is a character array (as declared) initialized with values from the string literal, but not a _string_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The major problem is, for an array defined like `char a[4] = ....` (with a size of 4 elements), using `if (a[4] ....)` is already off-by-one and causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You want to check for `a[3]`, as that is the last *valid* element.

That said, in your case, you don;t have room for null-terminator!!

Emphasizing the quote from `C11`, §6.7.9,

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character **if there is room or if the array is of unknown size**) initialize the elements of the array.

So, you need to either

- use an array size which has room for the null-terminator
- or, use an array of unknown size, like `char a[ ] = "1234";` where, the array size is automatically determined by the length of the supplied initializer (including the null-terminator.)

Comment: Nice to see the downvote, please do add a comment, too, I insist.

Comment: I don't get it too, you're absolutely right with your answer!

Comment: Thanks! I think that's the answer.

Comment: NMDV: On [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252826/2410359), [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh) for DV explanation itself. is controversial.  The only thing amiss I see here is "array of unknown size" s/b "array of unspecified size"

Answer (score 4):

It is **undefined behaviour** because you have trying to access array out of bound.

Do not specify the bound of a string initialized with a **string literal** because the compiler will automatically allocate sufficient space for entire string literal,including the terminating null character.

**C standard(c11 - 6.7.9 : paragraph 14) says:**

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>   literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
>   Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
>   character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
>   initialize the elements of the array.

So, does not specify the bound of a character array in the array initialize.

```
char a[] = "1234";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need one more place at the end of the array to store the `\0`. Declare the arrays with length `5`.

You can access the `n`th element of an array if the array has `n` elements. Here the size of the arrays are `4` bytes and you are trying to get the `5`th byte (as array indices in C start from `0`) when you do something like `if(a[4] == '\0')`.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the above code without specifying the array size, in that case all the 3 if statements will be executed, here as we have specified the array size and we know that the array of string will occupy 1 more char for NULL TERMINATION, but here we didn't give chance to the array to behave that way, therefore the compiler behaves randomly.